# Loss of "add user" after migrating dokuwiki

Tags: dokuwiki

I migrated an installation of dokuwiki from one server to another, following the instructions on the dokuwiki website. It worked (though I didn't test is as thoroughly as I should have), so I also upgraded the dokuwiki software itself.

Most of the website works fine, user people can still log in, etc. But the "add new user" form at the bottom of the user manager page is gone. I'm still listed as a part of the "admin" group.

**How can I get the add user form back onto the dokuwiki user manager page?**

Answer (score 1):

This was because the wiki software didn't have write permission. Use `chmod` to add write permission to the data directory and all of its files.